# python ImportError: cannot import name 'JHUData' from 'covsirphy.cleaning'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I installed the package used for modeling covid-19 with python, but I get an error

```
import covsirphy as cs
print(cs.get_version())
```

Error Msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/home/compt/PycharmProjects/covid19-sir/sir.py", line 1, in <module> import covsirphy
File "/home/compt/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/covsirphy/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>     from covsirphy.cleaning import Term, CleaningBase, DataLoader 

File "/home/compt/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/covsirphy/cleaning/__init__.py", line 15, in <module> m_imported = import_module(f"{__name__}.{m.stem}") 
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level

File "/home/compt/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/covsirphy/cleaning/example_data.py", line 6, in <module> from covsirphy.analysis.simulator import ODESimulator 

File "/home/compt/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/covsirphy/analysis/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>m_imported = import_module(f"{__name__}.{m.stem}")


File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 

File "/home/compt/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/covsirphy/analysis/sr_change.py", line 9, in <module>

from covsirphy.cleaning import Term, JHUData ImportError: cannot import name 'JHUData' from 'covsirphy.cleaning' (/home/compt/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/covsirphy/cleaning/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

Import directly from the library.

```
from covsirphy import Term, JHUData
```

Or alternatively, use your alias

```
from cs import Term, JHUData
```

https://github.com/lisphilar/covid19-sir/blob/master/covsirphy/__init__.py

Comment: Sorry I haven't tried either method but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Please kindly confirm that you are using [CovsirPhy version 2.5.3](https://github.com/lisphilar/covid19-sir/releases/tag/2.5.3) or newer versions.

If you installed it with pip, version number can be shown with `pip show covsirphy` command.

Comment: Hello there. my main purpose was not to learn the version. I am trying to make the examples in the link https://www.kaggle.com/lisphilar/covid-19-data-with-sir-model.
The version of covsirpyh I installed 2.6.0

Comment: Thank you. I thought this was fixed in 2.5.3, but seems not. Please share the method of installation you did and details of error message in this question or create a bug report in https://github.com/lisphilar/covid19-sir/issues

Comment: I could not reproduce the error in my locak environment and Kaggle Notebook.

Comment: Sorry for writing a late reply. I installed the package with pip. and I shared the error message details above. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your information! I need to try to reproduce the error with Pycharm. Could you use CovsirPhy with Jupyter Notebook/Lab or Google Collaboratory for a while?